# looping until a file gets created in python

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a csv file which is named as OUT_FILE. now I can see that file is not immediately created on the disk, so I want to wait until the file gets created.

below is the code to write the csv file:

```
with open(OUT_FILE, 'a') as outputfile:
    with open(INTER_FILE, 'rb') as feed:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        reader = csv.reader(feed, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:   
            reportable_jurisdiction=row[7]
        if '|' in reportable_jurisdiction:
            row[7]="|".join(sorted(list(row[7].split('|'))))
            print " reportable Jurisdiction with comma "+reportable_jurisdiction
        else:
            print "reportable Jurisdiction if single "+reportable_jurisdiction

        writer.writerow(row)
    feed.close()
    outputfile.close()
```

Now I have one file called FEED_FILE which actually the input for the OUT_FILE i.e. after wrting the data on OUT_FILE, the size of the OUT_FILE and FEED_FILE should be same.

so for the same I have written the below code :

```
while True:
    try:
        print'sleeping for 5 seconds'
        time.sleep(5)
        outputfileSize=os.path.getsize(OUT_FILE)

        if( outputfileSize ==FeedFileSize ):
            break
    except OSError:
        print " file not created "
        continue

print " file created !!"
```

now I don't know if this is executing since there are no errors and even print is not coming in output ?

any help?

Comment: Are you trying to run these in 'parallel' (threaded or in a multiprocess setting) or your `while` loop goes after you exit the `with` clause for your `outputfile`?

Comment: ioerror is not the same as oserror.

Comment: @zwer .. my while loop goes after exit to with clause.. the code is exactly same as mentioned above. nothing is changed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if file exist using python's **os** module?

```
import os

def wait_for_file(path):
  timeout = 300
  while timeout:
     if os.path.exists(path):
       # check if your condition of file size having
       # same as feed file size is met
       return
     timeout = timeout - 5
     sleep(5)
 raise Exception, "File was not created"
```

Comment: timeout is reached and throwing the exception "File was not created"

Comment: It had a missing sleep. But its just an idea . obviously you cant pluck it in directly !